# Checking an image against google

Tags: image, libcurl

I'm making a site where ppl will upload pictures and I would like to be able to check them against google to see if they are original or lifted off the web somewhere. I was thinking about doing this by analyzing the request made when using google images (the type of search where you upload an image and google finds where its from) and replicating it with libcurl. Does anyone have any thoughts on a good way to do this? google doesnt seem to provide an api for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're really talking about is a "reverse image search", which will hopefully give you some more leverage in further searching towards finding the information you need. I was going to write about my vague understanding of the process briefly but before I finished I found some previous questions similar to yours which do a far better job than I was:

[What algorithm could be used to identify if images are the "same" or similar, regardless of size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005115/what-algorithm-could-be-used-to-identify-if-images-are-the-same-or-similar-re)

[I wonder how reverse image search services like tineye.com work ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314375/i-wonder-how-reverse-image-search-services-like-tineye-com-work)

Comment: Thanks for the info but I'm not looking to write my own algorithms for this. I'd like to be able to leverage google for it.

Comment: If Google doesn't offer an API, your only option for leveraging their results is probably some form of terms-of-service violation like page-scraping (which is likely to be noticed and blocked systematically or otherwise noticed and shut down at some point). If you have any resources of note I suspect TinEye's commercial pay-to-play API (or a similar service elsewhere) is going to be the only real option for leveraging someone else's service.